# Masstransit Consumer is not working with Servicebus Topic

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics

Recently I am building a .net core worker application for consuming data from a Service Bus Topic and I am using the MassTransit for that.I have tried several option to implement it by searching web but nothing seems working.

I have written my consumer class like this

```
public class PublisherConsumer : IConsumer<NotificationPublishEvent>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<NotificationPublishEvent> context)
        {
            var checkoutEvent = context.Message;
            // Process the checkoutEvent here as per your requirement
            Console.WriteLine($"Received Event with JobId: {checkoutEvent.JobId}");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

In worker startup I have configured this way

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        
        var connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://xxx-notification.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=XXXZnHyPBx3YmqGNrKZa/0+XXX=";

        var subscriptionName = "notification-sub";

    services.AddMassTransit(config =>
    {
        config.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
        config.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();
        var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        config.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
        config.AddSagaStateMachines(entryAssembly);
        config.AddSagas(entryAssembly);
        config.AddActivities(entryAssembly);
        config.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(connectionString);
                cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<NotificationPublishEvent>(subscriptionName, ec =>
                {

                    ec.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
                    ec.UseDelayedRedelivery(x => x.Incremental(5, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));
                    ec.ConfigureConsumer<PublisherConsumer>(context);
                });
            });
        });

    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

In worker console I can see logs like this
Bus started: sb://aec-notification.servicebus.windows.net/

But it is not hitting the consumer though I have 18 messages in my subscription

What is the probable cause for this.

Ok I got one point I am publishing to notification topic and my subscription name notification-sub is created there  but in log the endpoint is showing as

Topic : EventBus.Messages.Events/NotificationPublishEvent ()

Subscription notification-sub (EventBus.Messages.Events/NotificationPublishEvent -> (null))

Endpoint Ready: sb://aec-notification.servicebus.windows.net/EventBus.Messages.Events/NotificationPublishEvent/Subscriptions/notification-sub

EventBus.Messages.Events created automatically why this happend

Thanks
Utpal Maity

Comment: Review the logs, set them to debug, then you'll see. Also, delayed redelivery does not work with subscription endpoints.

Comment: how to see the logs.The worker application only the log bus started as mentioned earlier.Is there any other ways to see the masstransit log and how to set it to debug

Comment: @ChrisPatterson getting this log 
dbug: MassTransit[0]
Endpoint Ready: sb://aec-notification.servicebus.windows.net/DEVVM011_NotificationWorker_bus_et5oyyn7yyybmxbfbdp5y4kwre?autodelete=300
dbug: MassTransit[0]
Topic: EventBus.Messages.Events/NotificationPublishEvent ()
dbug: MassTransit[0]
 Subscription notification-sub (EventBus.Messages.Events/NotificationPublishEvent -> (null))
dbug: MassTransit[0]
      Endpoint Ready: sb://aec-notification.servicebus.windows.net/EventBus.Messages.Events/NotificationPublishEvent/Subscriptions/notification-sub
info: MassTransit[0]

Comment: Ok I got one point I am publishing to notification topic and my subscription name notification-sub is created there  but in log the endpoint is showing as

 
 Topic : EventBus.Messages.Events/NotificationPublishEvent ()

 Subscription notification-sub (EventBus.Messages.Events/NotificationPublishEvent -> (null))

Endpoint Ready: sb://aec-notification.servicebus.windows.net/EventBus.Messages.Events/NotificationPublishEvent/Subscriptions/notification-sub

EventBus.Messages.Events created automatically why this happend

Comment: @Utpal x.UsingAzureServiceBus(configure: (context, cfg) =>
                        {
                            cfg.Host(connectionString: "connectionstring");
                            cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint("TopicName", " subscriptionName", e =>
                            {
                                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                            });
                            //cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);

                        });
                        
                    });
                    services.AddHostedService<worker>();